# Query not returning results though valid

Tags: mysql

I'm not getting results when I run this, but I definitely have rows that match the criteria. Thoughts?

```
SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `child_id` IS NULL AND `parent_id`='128102'
```

I want it to return rows where `child_id` is null AND `parent_id` equals 128102, but it isn't.

Comment: If `parent_id` is an integer, drop the single quotes. Otherwise, there's no reason your query shouldn't work. You're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Dropping the single quotes has no effect.

Comment: Try AND TRIM(`parent_id`)='128102'

Comment: Can we see what `SELECT * from elements` returns or at least what the expected results are

Comment: Nope, trim didn't fix it

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Please post the output of DESCRIBE `elements`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO if you are wanting the default value of `child_id`, it is listed as NULL when I do DESCRIBE.

Comment: Do you get any results if you change it to `SELECT * FROM elements WHERE child_id ='' AND parent_id='128102'` This is why seeing the data you are trying to query would be useful for us

Comment: @jzworkman yes, I do... why does that work but not IS NULL?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Why is it so difficult for you to post the `DESCRIBE`? If you don't want help, then don't ask for it.

Comment: Most likely the values for those are empty strings instead of being `NULL`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO because the variable names I posted aren't actually the ones I'm using, and the only way to post it formatted is as a picture. I can only post pictures on the question and not in a comment.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add a picture

Comment: @jzworkman that's odd, because the "default value" is supposed to be NULL

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII It could be based on who enters the data, the data might be entered as an empty string instead of leaving it blank/null

Comment: Hmm, the default value option only let's me choose "none" because it is a text field. So it can't store a NULL value for some reason.

Comment: Is there a reason to be using a text field for an id as opposed to `varchar` or even better `int`? `Text` fields always store the value in a blob(file) instead of inline in the table.  It should really not be used for small sets of data, and it is even considered poor performance for large amounts of text now.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII If you had posted the structure of your table, this would have been solved in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize all of my comments above:

Since your column `child_id` is a text field it cannot be `NULL` so you need to change it to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `child_id` = '' AND `parent_id`='128102'
```

But as I also stated you really should be using a `varchar` or better yet an `int` for your id fields.  `Text` fields always store the value in a blob(file) instead of inline in the table. It should really not be used for small sets of data, and it is even considered poor performance for large amounts of text now.

Comment: What is considered "good" performance for large amounts of data? I might use a varchar, but not an int as the ID will be alphanumeric.

Comment: Basically `TEXT` has been deprecated and is not needed to be used as `VARCHAR(MAX)` can be used instead.  And unless your id's are going to be longer than 64k characters(which would be insane) there is no reason to ever use `TEXT` as `TEXT` columns cannot be indexed and require an entire row read.  You can find more performance metrics here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964#msg-105964

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `child_id` IS NULL AND trim(`parent_id`)='128102';
```

if it is not working try following

```
  SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `child_id` IS NULL AND `parent_id`=128102;
```

If both of the above queries not working please tell me that datatype of both `child_id` and `parent_id`

Also provide result of below query

```
    SELECT child_id,length(child_id),parent_id,length(parent_id) 
FROM `elements` WHERE   `parent_id` like '%128102%'
```

Comment: If you read the comments above this was already suggested and did not work.